# Javascript function undefined

Tags: javascript, function, date, undefined

```
// How many days between two dates
function gDaysBetweenDates(date1, date2) {

    var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime();


    return Math.round(Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

}
```

Date1 and date2 being passed are Date objects with values like:

> Tue Mar 09 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT
>   Standard Time)

I get a problem when trying to extract the time, it says getTime is undefined.  When I try and create a new date object with the dates passed in via:

```
var dateNew = new Date(date1);
```

I get the error, date is in invalid format.

Comment: `new Date('Tue Mar 09 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)');` works. Check the values passed are not `undefined` (or anything else for that matter) (`alert` them inside `gDaysBetweenDates`)

Comment: I suspect that those values are *not* actually Date instances ...

Comment: How the date string is generated? Do you control its format?

Comment: It's passed from a 2D array.  The value stored in the 2D array is a date object.  I've tried everything to get it to MS!

Comment: That date value i posted was from alert(date1)

Comment: @Tom date object of what language? JavaScript? ASP.NET?

Comment: It was a string date, which I parsed with JS and converted to a JS Date obejct

Comment: Can you store the timestamp (date1.getTime()) in the array instead of the string format?

Comment: I ended up passing the .getTime() value through instead of the date object which works fine.

Comment: Cheers, let me know if you want my last comment as Answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last problem, run `date1.constructor` to see what kind of object `date1` is. If it is a number is should work as you've written it. If it is a string, you have to make sure that it is formatted as a date. If it's anything but number or string you have an invalid type.

Also, make sure to check that `date1` isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some type problems. The Date constructor only accepts millisecond Numbers or date strings, not a date object. The other error sounds like you think something is a Date object which is in fact not. (null? a string?)